# Cannot use a placeholder for database name value in PDO prepare statement - causes SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, prepared-statement

I got this error while creating a database in php using pdo. Below is the part that causes this error.

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    // create database 
    $db_query = $conn->prepare("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ?");
    $db_query->execute([$myDB]);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo  "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}
```

I could create the database just fine without using prepare, so I wonder if prepare cannot be used to create database by design.

Comment: Why are you putting spaces between your code as `  -> `? This is invalid

Comment: a `?` placeholder cannot be used for a database/column/table identifier.  They are only appropriate for values.  You should instead validate the `$myDB` string against something like a regular expression, assuming you have strict limits on how the database should be named.